# How can I allocate contiguous physical memory blocks in C++ with Windows OS?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I'm writing an application-level memory manager in C++ for a game I'm working on. My memory manager allocates enough memory at the start of each "game session" so that no dynamic memory allocations are necessary during the game session and this improves performance greatly. I was able to gain another big improvement in performance by sorting the list of "game objects" such that they get updated in the order that they reside in the application's virtual address space. So this did help reduce some cache misses.

Now I would like to take this a step further and make it even more cache friendly. I realize that for Windows OS each application (process) has it's own virtual address space which maps to (non-contiguous) physical memory. But is there a way I can request contiguous chunks of physical memory for use by my memory manager? (and will remain contiguous in the physical memory space?).

Comment: Cache is usually based on virtual address space, at least on X86, so the only gain is due to 4K page boundaries being crossed, affecting ram access times slightly.

Comment: Are you sure your game engine sophisticated enough that you need to think about memory allocation granularity? You'll get more benefit from using more cache-friendly data structures than from custom memory manager (that most likely won't be anyhow better than default one).

Comment: In case someone writing drivers stumbles on this question, drivers can use `MmAllocateContiguousMemory()`. That being said, even if you could, that would be a BAD idea. The odds of the memory allocation failing would be crazy high for the kind of size you would need for a game engine.

Comment: Also, contiguous memory is generally a *bad* idea on multiprocessor systems: it will perform well on one CPU, but horribly on other CPUs. That's why the kernel stripes memory by default.

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate a bit, what problem are you trying to solve? Are your structures and game objects that complex when initializing that dynamically allocating them causes such massive lag that it's noticeable to the user? How much RAM are you grabbing, and what happens if you can't grab that exact amount? Are you sure your memory manager will work as intended on other systems (e.g. your RAM is not the users RAM)?

Comment: @rcgldr Thanks, I will look into this for x86. I do plan to run on some other platforms and will see how it is implemented there as well.